# How to install the newest version of a signed apk over the old version of .abb?

Tags: android, apk, bundle, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

I already uplaoded bundle on playstore in past and
now i just created a signed apk of updated version of my app
then first install app from playstore of older version and then
try to install updated version of signed apk on that is it installed or not?

Means my question is that in past i had to uplaoded **.abb** and now for testing purpose i'm trying to install updated **signed apk** from sd card. it gives error "app not installed". so sould i install updated apk over older .abb

- Play Protect off in playstore
- Version code also updated
- DB version also updated

Comment: You can try Internal app sharing feature on Play Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm got answer and may be it's helpful to others.

If you upload .aab previously then unable to install signed APK over old .abb installed App. so you need to upload .abb on play store then after you can able to install over old uploaded .abb and if you uploaded signed APK in past then and then you can install new signed APK over older APK